# VBA Excel File not compiling: Sub or Function not defined

Tags: vba, excel, compiler-errors

Here is the associated code:
It says the error is in the definition of the function operation()
I feel like I need to include something, but I am not sure what.
Can anybody please advise on what I need to do?
I know to go to Tools > References > .. but after that I am not sure.

```
Sub operation()
'
' Macro5 Macro
'

'
Dim Erw, firstRow, lastRow
firstRow = 1
Last Row = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For Erw = firstRow To lastRow
    Dim newRow
    newRow = firstRow + 4
    Range("B" & newRow).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Range("B" & newRow)
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1", _
        Destination:=Range("$D$5"))
        .Name = "collections1504_1"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    nextRow = nextRow + 1
    Next Erw

    Range("D3").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("C5").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("D5:P143").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.QueryTable.Delete
    Selection.ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: If you set `Option Explicit` at the top of your code, it will automatically highlight and capitalize your variable names for you as you type. Anything that doesn't highlight/capitalize properly is a typo. Very handy tool for finding these errors. (for example, I'd `Dim LastRow as Integer`, then typing `lastrow` would get changed to `LastRow`, so I know it's right. If I'd typed `last row` it wouldn't get capitalized correctly, so I'd know something was wrong)

Answer (score 3):

You've got a typo in your variable names. You have:

```
Last Row = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

but it should be:

```
lastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

If you put

```
Option Explicit
```

at the top of your module, you get a slightly more helpful error message.  You really should get in to the habit of including that as it will check to make sure all of your variables are declared.  It's so helpful in fact, that you can have it set at module creation by default.  In the VBA IDE go to Tools => Options => Tick the box labeled "Require Variable Declaration".

Answer (score 1):

As the compiler tells you (and halts on the line), the function `Last` is not defined: there is a space too many:

```
Last Row
```

should be

```
lastRow
```